# Who is the original author of GNU ld?

Tags: history, gnu, ld

Author information can be difficult to find for projects whose histories go back long before their git repositories. According to Wikipedia, Richard Stallman wrote [gcc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection), and Dean Elsner wrote [GNU as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Assembler).

Who wrote the GNU linker, ld?

Answer (score 3):

The GNU linker ? A too [*Big Fucking Deal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_File_Descriptor_library) for Stallmann.

When linking object files, the first idea is to present a common abstract view of them.
This is recorded as being the idea of David Henkel-Wallace from [Cygnus Solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygnus_Solutions) which produced the [*Binary File Descriptor library*](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/BFD.html)

The GNU Linker is based on this and proposed as part of the [binutils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Binutils) GNU package, a collection of tools initially developed by Cygnus' programmers.

Not hard to list them all reading the [major contributors of early releases](https://github.com/alisw/gcc-toolchain/blob/master/binutils-2.25.1/ld/ChangeLog-9197) among which [John Gilmore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Gilmore_(activist)), Steve Chamberlain and Per Bothner to name a few.

Comment: Didn't think to look there, thanks.